# What is the reason asio doesn't do any delay?

Tags: asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I am new to asio.

Here is guide I was following writing my daytime tcp-server: https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.18.1/doc/asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html . I was trying to reproduce a reasonable example that would show that asunchronous code is actually asynchronous. I didn't modify anything else, just small piece of code in `tcp_server` class. I am adding this delay in order to see that after we are waiting timer to expire, we can gracefully handle other client connections/requests. So, did I miss something? Because in my case delay basically doesn't work ;(

```
void handle_accept(const tcp_connection::pointer &new_connection,
                   const asio::error_code &error) {

    asio::steady_timer timer(io_context_,  asio::chrono::seconds(5));

    std::cout << "Before timer" << std::endl;

    timer.async_wait(std::bind(&tcp_server::handle_wait, this, error, new_connection));
}

void handle_wait(asio::error_code &ec, const tcp_connection::pointer &new_connection) {
    if (!ec) {
        new_connection->start();
    }

    std::cout << "Inside timer" << std::endl;

    start_accept();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void handle_accept(const tcp_connection::pointer &new_connection,
                       const asio::error_code &error) {

        asio::steady_timer timer(io_context_,  asio::chrono::seconds(5));

        std::cout << "Before timer" << std::endl;

        timer.async_wait(std::bind(&tcp_server::handle_wait, this, error, new_connection));
    }
```

The `timer` is a local variable.

`async_wait` returns immediately, without blocking.

The function exits, destructing the `timer`. The `timer` cancels all pending operations (with `error::operation_aborted`).

Make sure the lifetime of the timer extends well enough to allow for it expire (or at least until it stops being relevant). *In your case there will probably already be a `tcp::acceptor` member in your class, and the timer could reside next to it*.

Comment: Thank you. Now I undarstand what is going wrong. However what do you mean by "and the time could reside next to it"? How can I do that?

Comment: In your [linked sample code](https://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.18.1/doc/asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3/src.html), move the timer declaration to the line after "tcp::acceptor acceptor_;" Be sure to initialize it in the constructor, again like the `acceptor_`. This is another [class member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class#Member_specification)

Comment: Yes, it helped. Thank you once more ;)